# set cover with the minimal maximal intersection size

Tags: algorithm

Given a universe U and a family S of subsets of U, find a cover that is a subfamily C <= S of sets whose union is U. For each c in C, let i be the intersection of c and U. The constraints are

- we wanted to minimize the maximal size of i of all subsets in C.
- the size of C is minimal.

For example,

```
S = {{1,2}, {1,2,3}, {3, 4}}
U = {1,2,3}
```

The C is {{1,2}, {2,4}} but not {{1,2,3}}. Because the minimal maximal size of i of {{1,2}, {3,4}} is 2, while {{1,2,3}}'s is 3.

This seems related to [the traditional set coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It is like this:

```
Given a universe U and a family S of subsets of U, a cover is a subfamily C <= S of sets whose union is U. Find a C, s.t. the size of C is minimal.
```

What is the name of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As stated, I don't know if anybody would name it. For each element in U, find the set in C of minimal size that contains the target element. A cover consisting of all of these choices covers the set and is a best possible cover by your measure, because the largest set in it cannot be replaced by a smaller one.

I don't have a name, but I can point you at related problems. If you don't have a good idea of how to balance your two objectives, you might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#Scalarizing and try and optimize some linear combination of them. Since one objective is NP-complete, you might end up considering all possible covers, at which point the extra complexity of calculating the weighted sum of two objectives might be the least of your problems.

If you try and minimize the number of sets used to create a cover, subject to a constraint on the maximum size of the sets involved, you have a nice hierarchy of three problems.

If all of the sets involved are of size 1, you hardly have a problem at all - you obviously need one set for each object covered.

If all of the sets involved are of size 2, I think you can regard the sets as edges, and use a (polynomial time) algorithm for minimum edge cover as at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover.

If all of the sets involved are of size 3, a special case of your problem is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching, which unfortunately is NP-complete.

Comment: Sorry. I mis-stated the question. Please read the edited question.